# Google AutoComplete Not Populating TableView

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places, gmsautocomplete

I am using Google AutoComplete to search Addresses.  I am getting a result in the console, however, this is not populating into the TableView.

- I am in the main queue when reloading the table.
- I am getting a print count of the number of objects in the result.

### SearchResultsController

```
extension ResultsController: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.autocorrectionType = .yes
        if searchController.isActive {
            searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        }
        if searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
            self.searchResults.removeAll()
        } else {
            guard let query = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            GMSPlacesClient.shared().autocompleteQuery(query, bounds: nil, filter: self.filteredResults) { (results, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error as Any)
                    return
                } else {
                    guard let results = results else { return }
                    self.searchResults.append(contentsOf: results)
                    print(self.searchResults)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchResults.removeAll()
    }
}
```

### TableView

```
extension ResultsController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let resultsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resultsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let resultsAttributedFullText = searchResults[indexPath.row].attributedFullText.string
        resultsCell.textLabel?.text = resultsAttributedFullText
        return resultsCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

### Console Output

```
[GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x60000053d6e0: "Whittier Boulevard, Whittier, CA, USA", id: EiVXaGl0dGllciBCb3VsZXZhcmQsIFdoaXR0aWVyLCBDQSwgVVNBIi4qLAoUChIJ988tx8bTwoARp1jTzq6WINISFAoSCfeHelWG08KAEVokQMFHfagn, types: (
    route,
    geocode
), GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x60000053f150: "Whitehorse Road, Balwyn VIC, Australia", id: EiZXaGl0ZWhvcnNlIFJvYWQsIEJhbHd5biBWSUMsIEF1c3RyYWxpYSIuKiwKFAoSCREWtq2qQNZqEQJK4PmVuEWbEhQKEglDvWU1O0HWahEw2IwhdVYEBQ, types: (
    route,
    geocode
), GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x600000532280: "Whiteman Street, Southbank VIC, Australia", id: EilXaGl0ZW1hbiBTdHJlZXQsIFNvdXRoYmFuayBWSUMsIEF1c3RyYWxpYSIuKiwKFAoSCe96AVJUXdZqEeCPutYFxDBlEhQKEgkP4YsKRV3WahHA_owhdVYEBQ, types: (
    route,
    geocode
), GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x600000531d40: "Whitechapel Road, London, UK", id: EhxXaGl0ZWNoYXBlbCBSb2FkLCBMb25kb24sIFVLIi4qLAoUChIJtVKaXcwcdkgR-UK_lKqNnh0SFAoSCamRx0IRO1oCEXoliDJDoPjE, types: (
    route,
    geocode
), GMSAutocompletePrediction 0x600000532400: "Whitehouse Lane, Yeadon, Leeds, UK", id: EiJXaGl0ZWhvdXNlIExhbmUsIFllYWRvbiwgTGVlZHMsIFVLIi4qLAoUChIJX11vv3ZYeUgR7a_1SItTcAgSFAoSCb1BkiJ1WHlIEdu33wgccaPf, types: (
    route,
    geocode
)]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

### Update

[image: Break point output on .reloadData()]

Above is the breakpoint on .reloadData() on the tableView.
Therefore, the table is being reloaded and the array is being populated with the results.  The issue is cellForRowAtIndex isnt being called for some reason!?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to add your tableview
Please check below code

```
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps

class DirectionsViewController: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txfFromLocation.addTarget(self, action: #selector(autocompleteClicked), for: .editingDidBegin)
    }

    @objc func autocompleteClicked (sender:UITextField!){
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK:- GMSAUTOCOMPLETEDELEGATES
    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is for Googles' "out of the box" UI.  I require a customised UI.

Comment: yes.. ok. Will let you know if I find anything as your requirement

Comment: Looking at your code. I see tableview.delegate = self and tableview.datasource = self is missing

Comment: I have that in my ViewDidLoad

Comment: Try adding it to --- DispatchQueue.main.async {
tableview.delegate = self 
tableview.datasource = self
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

Comment: It hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Try adding a debug to check if the tableview code is executed and if the debug is coming to numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: for some reason cellForRowAtIndexPath isnt getting called.

Comment: try moving your tableview code to the main viewcontroller. The problem is reloadData() function is not working

Comment: The problem is reload data is being called before the data in searchResults is fully loaded. Try to add a delay before a reloaddata function is called. just a timebeing solution so that we know the exact error

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have a main view controller "MapController" with searchController "ResultsController" My tableView is in the Results Controller because thats where the results will load.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}

Comment: I've added this with no effect.